# Automapper not mapping all fields that are configured

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a db objects that i would like to map to my view object in my application, but not every property getting mapped.

here is my `Automapper` set up:

Here is my View class that i would like `AutoMapper` to map to

```
public class CustomerDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }


public class Email
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string EmailName { get; set; }
}

  public class Address
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Here is db classes:

```
    public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public virtual CustomerBalance Balance { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }

    public class Email
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string EmailName { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }

 public class Address
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

here is how i set up my configuration for `AutoMapper`

```
  Mapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.AddProfile<CustomerProfile>();
            }); 


  public class CustomerProfile : Profile
    {

        public CustomerProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<DataModels.Phone, Phone>();
            CreateMap<DataModels.Email, Email>();
            CreateMap<DataModels.Address, Address>();
            CreateMap<DataModels.CustomerPin, Pin>()
                .ForMember(x => x.PinNumber, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Pin))
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                ;

            CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDetails>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Phones, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Phones))
                .ForMember(x => x.Emails, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Emails))
                .ForMember(x => x.Balance, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Balance.Balance))
                .ForMember(x => x.Pins, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Pin))
                .ForMember(x => x.Addresses, y => y.MapFrom(s => s.Address))

                ;

            CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDetails>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is is that everything getting mapped as expected, except the `Addresses`property and `Balance` on my `CustomerDetails.cs`. The list collection is null even though i specified to map it from a member.  However, email List is getting mapped appropriately.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is just a basic check but you might want to check that your namespaces are correct for example fully qualify the namespaces in these lines CreateMap<DataModels.Phone, Phone>(); and others because I have seen some people who map to the same object by mistake. Another basic check is to ensure you have exactly the same names in both the model and entity classes.

Comment: AS @AliK - check namespaces, Then make a dump of your input data (serialize to json?) to make sure the data is there. Maybe issue with Lazy Loading?

Comment: You've not shown how you're calling AutoMapper with the data - if it's using `Map`, then I suspect lazy loading.  If you're calling `ProjectTo`, then this is probably not the case.